# Word for "at least two different values" or "two or more values"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word (or maybe a compound word) that means something that can have "one of at least two different values", or "one of two or more values". My context is that I am trying to define "theoretical concept" for my academic research. The word I currently have is "measurable concept", with the understanding that something that can be measured in any way (even as simply as true or false) is a measurable concept, and thus can serve as a theoretical concept.

By "one of two", I mean that it can be either true or it can be false; it can be one of those two values (true/false). By "at least two" or "two or more", I mean that it could have more than two possible values (e.g., true/false is two values; A/B/C is three values; 1 to 10 is ten values), but the concept has one value from those options at a time.

The word "measurable" is the best that I have come up with, since to me, assigning a value true/false, A/B/C, 1-10, etc. is a type of measurement, but that word does not intuitively give the idea of "at least two different values" and "measurement" has not been intuitively understood that way when I have tried to discuss my meaning with people.

Here are a few examples of how the word (an adjective) might be used:

> An [adjective] concept might be a number, a binary value, a textual
> category, a date, or a complex combination of any of these.
>
> These ideas can be easily adapted to think of them in an [adjective]
> way, and thus these adapted versions become theoretical concepts.
>
> A proposition is essentially a formal statement of a relationship
> between [adjective] concepts.

**Is there an English word (ideally a single word, but a compound word would be suitable) that intuitively means possessing one of at least two different values, that is one of two or more values?**

---

**Edit:**

A comment suggested the noun "variable", so I should have clarified why that would not be appropriate for my context. In social science research, the word "variable" is suitably used by some philosophical perspectives (usually called "positivism") to indicate a concept that has such properties that I am describing. However, I want to also speak to non-positivist social scientists (such as interpretivists) who strongly object to the word "variable" to describe the kind of research element that they use because for them, that is based on a natural science (and mathematical) philosophy of science. So, the word that I am looking for might be an adjective that is synonomous with "variable", but the word "variable" is not suitable for my purposes.

Comment: This is the definition of a **variable**. Variables have particular values depending on constraints involved (eg **today**'s date).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Greybeard, I assure you, this question has nothing to do with mathematics. My latest edit should make that clearer. I'm sorry that I forgot to clarify that important point in my original question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I have edited the question to clarify why "variable" is not suitable for my purposes. I'm sorry that I forgot to clarify that important point in my original question.

Comment: I considered "quantised", but it doesn't work if the range is continuous (e.g. real numbers). You might want to consider talking about the *metric* of the concept, since the term *concept* suggests a description rather than an associated set of values.

Comment: 'Binary' has the sense 'consisting of two parts / elements'. 'Plural' means 'pertaining to more than one [element]'.